# Network Service

Tags: network

I am trying to learn about computer networks. I often come across the term "network service". When searching a bit, it is told that for example DHCP or HTTP are services. I don't understand this because for me DHCP and HTTP are protocols, and I guess that protocols and a "network services" are 2 different things.

So what exactly is a "network service"? Is it an application in which a protocol is programmed?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DHCP and HTTP are protocols, but they are also services. Those are protocols to speak with servers that perform a function or service for you: DHCP is used to communicate with a DHCP server in order to get configuration information for your host, and HTTP is a protocol to communicate with an HTTP (Web) server in order to get web pages.

In general these type of protocols and services are off-topic here because they are applications or protocols above OSI layer-4.